# Compute Gal($\mathbb{Q}(w^{k})/\mathbb{Q})$ up to isomorphism, for all k $\in \mathbb{Z}$, where $w=e^\frac{2\pi i }{10}$

Tags: galois-theory

Compute Gal($\mathbb{Q}(w^{k})/\mathbb{Q})$ up to isomorphism, for all k $\in \mathbb{Z}$, where $w=e^\frac{2\pi i }{10}$

So I have got for k=1

That $\mathbb{Q}(w) $ contains 9 "roots" $w, w^2, w^3 ... w^9$

let the Q-automorphisms be $\sigma _{p}(w)=w^p$ for $1\leq p \leq 9 $

So is Gal($\mathbb{Q}(w)/\mathbb{Q})$={$\sigma _1 , \sigma_2, \sigma_3,  \sigma_4, \sigma_5, \sigma_6, \sigma_7, \sigma_8, \sigma_9$}

And then for k=2,

$\mathbb{Q}(w^2) $ contains $w^2, w^4, w^6, w^8 $
let the Q-automorphisms be $\sigma _{p}(w^2)=w^{2p}$ for $1\leq p \leq 4 $

So is Gal($\mathbb{Q}(w)/\mathbb{Q})$={$\sigma _1 , \sigma_2, \sigma_3 , \sigma_4$ }  ?

and do you carry on in a similar fashion until k=9?

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes in your answers.

You are correct in stating that an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ maps $\omega$ to some power $\omega^n$. However, $n = 5$ does not happen:
to see why, I invite you to compute the exact value of $\omega^5$. In the exact same way but slightly less obvious, $n = 2$ is also impossible (compute the minimal polynomials of $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ and check that they are different!). There are a few other impossible values: which ones exactly ?

Now you should have a quite simple criterion for the possible values of $n$, and this will give you the exact value of the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\omega)/\mathbb Q$.

This solves your problem for $k = 1$. Fortunately, this was the only “hard” case. Now you may easily check that the collection of all fields $\mathbb Q(\omega^k)$ actually only contains three different fields, one of which is $\mathbb Q$. So there are actually only two different Galois groups in your list (plus the trivial group).